# jQuery is not working on dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery:

```
$('#Item').selectpicker({
    liveSearch: true
}).ajaxSelectPicker({
    ajax: {
        url: '<?php echo base_url().'
        index.php / AJAX / select_searching '?>', // Required.
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            q: '{{{q}}}',
            column: 'English_company_name',
            Table: 'transport'
        }
    },
    preprocessData: function(data) {
        return data;
    },
    preserveSelected: false
});
```

This code is not working on dynamically created element. How can I apply this code on dynamically created elements? Sorry for my weak English. I created dynamic element just by using simple onclick event.

Comment: Run this code after you create the element.

Comment: What's error showing on console?

Comment: Also, just so it's thrown out there, `$('#Item')` says there will only be one of these items, since id's cannot be repeated in a single page.

Comment: `using simple onclick event.`, seen as your using jQuery, use a delgated event instead.. eg..  `$(document).on("click", "#item", function () {})`  Like @Taplar said using duplicate ID's not really the best idea.  A class might be better.

Comment: A delegated listener will not help with the element not being initialized with the selectpicker logic, which the question seems to be about.

Comment: @Taplar  Yes, your probably right, think the title is not really correct, it's not a jQuery issue, more a selectpicker one..

Comment: @Keith Yes I am using Class not a duplicate ID. I forgot to replace # with .

Comment: @ShahRushabh you are going to have to perform this initialization on each new element you create.  The element specifically, so you do not double initialize the previously created elements.  Jquery has the concept of a delegated listener for elements created in the future.  To my knowledge, there is no such concept in jquery as a delegated initializer.  You have to perform that logic yourself at the point that the logic creates the elements that need to be initialized.